# How to hide the authorization form when the user successfully signs in

Tags: php

How do I hide the authorization form when the user is signed in? Instead, I want the user to see: `Welcome, %username%`.

#### My code so far

```
<?if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])):?>
<form action="testreg.php" method="post"  }>
<p>
<label><span">Username:</span></span><br>
</label>
<input name="login" type="text"  size="25" maxlength="15">
 </p>
 <p>
<label><span class="style3">Password:</span><br>
</labe l>
<input name="password" type="password" class="style3" size="13"       
 maxlength="15">   
 </p>
   <p><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Enter">    
 <a href="reg.php" class="style4">Need an account?</</a></p>
</form>

 <?php

if (empty($_SESSION['login']) or empty($_SESSION['id']))
{
  
echo "You have signed in<br><a href='#'>Available only for you</a>";
}
else
{


echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['login']."<br><a  href='link'>Profile</a>";
}
?>
 <?endif?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give your form an ID like this

```
<form id="loginForm" action="testreg.php" method="post">
```

and in your PHP where you welcome the user, throw in some inline-style.

```
if (empty($_SESSION['login']) or empty($_SESSION['id']))
{
    echo "You have signed in<br><a href='#'>Available only for you</a>";
}
else
{
    echo ' //Add this bit here
      <style>
       #loginForm{
         display:none!important;
       }
      </style>
    ';

echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['login']."<br><a  href='link'>Profile</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this way you don't need to go on other page for signin

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<form action="testreg.php" method="post"  }>
<p>
<label><span">Username:</span></span><br>
</label>
<input name="login" type="text"  size="25" maxlength="15">
 </p>
 <p>
<label><span class="style3">Password:</span><br>
</labe l>
<input name="password" type="password" class="style3" size="13"       
 maxlength="15">   
 </p>
   <p><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Enter">    
 <a href="reg.php" class="style4">Need an account?</</a></p>
</form>
<?php $form = ob_get_clean(); ?>
```

//logic goes here

```
if (empty($_SESSION['login']) or empty($_SESSION['id']))
{
    echo $form;
}
else
{

echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['login']."<br><a  href='link'>Profile</a>";
}
```